# Htaccess redirect 301 not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect 301 my old domain to new one, and also an indexed old page to new page. here is the code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%A7/?$ http://newdomain.com/%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%A7 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but both not working... any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rule with `mod_alias` rules
2. Keep specific redirects before generic catch-all redirects.

You can have it as:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^\xD8\xAB\xD8\xA8\xD8\xAA-\xD8\xB1\xD8\xAA\xD8\xA8\xD9\x87-\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xDA\xA9\xD8\xB3\xD8\xA7/?$ /foo-bar [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's not working yet, I think there is a problem in my host, a question: in domain control panel, what should I do? park old domain to new? or set directory to same folder.

Comment: it's working now but only old domain redirected to new but old page not redirected... any idea?

Comment: here is: http://www.olddomain.com/%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%A7

Comment: see updated answer. You need to use `\xD8` (hex) to match `%D*`.

Comment: Thanks, it's ok now but a small problem is it's redirect /newpage/ to /newpage.php , I want to remove .php, how can i do this?

Comment: No this rule won't add `.php` extension on its own. Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess